# ASP.NET Core Web API : my api works on localhost but not on my plesk webserver

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, plesk, webapi, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have build an ASP.NET Core Web API and it's working fine on my machine testing it with postmann, all is beautiful, but when I put it in production on my plesk web server, it always says error 404 not found.

I have tried to create a sub domain but same thing, I have change the application url in the `launchsetting.json` file like so and also change the database to the one I have on the server need help please

```
"profiles": {
    "NHLStatsAndSalaryAPI": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",           
      "applicationUrl": "https://apinhl.nhldynastypool.com/",      
      "environmentVariables": {
        //"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
       "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      }
    },
```

Here's my file tree on my web server:

[image: file tree on my webserver]

I have tried to build my app when all was working fine on localhost and change the application url to the one on my plesk webserver. I expected to be able to use it the same way I use it on localhost. I have put all the project on the plesk server but still cant use my api at all was working fine in localhost but not on webserver

Comment: Is ASP.NET runtime installed on your machine? How you published your project - is it framework-dependent or self-contained?

Comment: There are so many things that can go wrong in here. How are you deploying? Have you looked into the logs of the web server? How is the web server configured? When you say it is 'not working', what exactly is the behaviour? Are you getting any error when you hit the end point? Or simply the server cannot be reached? Please provide more information.

Comment: yeah asp.net is installed on the plesk webserver i run my .net website on it. The way im deploying it it just by runing my code and copy past it in my webserver and changing the application url in the json file, but even in my dev code is not working when i put the application url of my webserver it is only working when i use the localhost and the "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" = "Development"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place your files under httpdocs (replacing the already existing web.config file).

If you do so an [asp.net core] icon should popup in your domain panel and the api will respond as it did in localhost.

Plesk requires you to put all the deploy files under httpdocs.

If you dont the app won't start.